# How stream reader & writer work in C#?

Tags: c#, uwp

Please see my questions in the comments of the sample code:

```
var fileStream = file.OpenStreamForReadAsync(); // [1]: Is the file stored in memory
                                                // when opened as stream?
var reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
string line;
while(!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    line = await reader.ReadLineAsync(); // [2]: If answer of [1] is "no", how the reader 
                                         // works when reading a line, does it read from
                                         // disk everytime?
    ...
}
```

And the same questions for a StreamWriter, when writing a line, does it write directly to the disk, or to the memory temporarily?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about Stream Reader.

Comment: You never write to a file directly, always to memory.  But that is an abstraction provided by the OS, it makes file writes very efficient.  Data is written to the disk lazily in the background.  Your program has no idea that this is what is actually happening.   Specific to UWP, such writes don't actually write to the file you opened.  Not until you close the stream.  That prevents you from accidentally destroying files because your program crashed or the disk ran out of space.  Your program has no idea that this is what is actually happening.  This info won't make you code any differently.

Comment: The [MSDN page on StreamReader.Read()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ath1fht8(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) mentions a buffer, so I would guess that it buffers as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter uses a buffer. It flushes to disc when you explicitly flush it, at the end of its `using` block, or when you call `Close` or `Dispose` on the stream. You can also set it to auto-flush.

In terms of reading, what would it do *other* than read from disc every time? You get a result, don't you? How would it come up with the result without actually doing a disc read?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for the StreamReader, I mean when it reads a line, does it read only one line from disk, or, when I open the file as a stream, a part of the file content is already stored in the memory (like a buffer)?

Comment: @sudoer It doesn't make sense for it to buffer because it doesn't know in advance how much of the file you're going to read.